# Migrate from windows mail to outlook express

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, outlook-express, windows-mail

I need to downgrade from Windows Vista to Windows XP. Is it possible to import mails and address book from Windows Mail to Outlook Express?

Comment: Outlook Express is insecure. Thunderbird would be a better bet.

Comment: @lain: or he can prefer Outlook express for personal reasons.

Comment: I was doing this for my friend, I 'm not software evangelist and I know he I happy with Outlook Express. Any way, could You give ane example of known non patched bug in Outlook Express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the messages use this method:

1. On the Vista computer, create a New Folder on the Desktop.
2. Open Windows Mail and position the window and New Folder so that you can see both.
3. Select the e-mail messages you want to go to Outlook Express, and drag them to the New Folder.
4. Put the new Folder onto removable media.
5. Attach the removable media to the XP computer.
6. Open Outlook Express and position the window and New Folder so that you can see both.
7. Open the New Folder and Select All.
8. Drag the selected messages into the list of messages for the Inbox or desired folder in Outlook Express (just make sure that the target folder is open).
9. Delete the New Folder from both computers and the removable media.

*[Source: Exporting Windows Mail back to Outlook Express](http://www.vista4beginners.com/node/182)*

Comment: Thank You. I had some problems with booting to Windows, but then everything went smoothly.

Comment: you're more than welcome.

Comment: Most of the solutions out there seem to center around email itself, not mail rules. I have like 80+ mailing rules, and it is a pain to recreate them from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

For contacts, I think that you can export in a common format (which is quite usual), the CSV, like described on [that link](http://www.simplehelp.net/2009/07/06/how-to-backup-your-windows-live-contacts/).

<strike>It might be more complicated for mails, though.</strike> Molly's answer describes the way to do for mail, I'm surprised you can do that as easily as a drag and drop.

Comment: Thank you. It is a pity that I can not mark two answers as correct